# Displaying images in scrollable div

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have an array of images (src url for them) and I want to display them in a line, like so:

[Image1] [image2] [image3]

If there are a lot images I'd want the `<div>` they are in to become scrollable, on the x-axis, so that the images are still in a line.

This is what I've got now:

```
<div style="overflow-x:scroll" class="col-md-12">
    <span ng-repeat="item in images" >
        <a ng-href="{{item.ServerRelativeUrl}}" target="_blank">
            <img width="128" ng-src="{{item.ServerRelativeUrl}}" alt="Description">
        </a>
    </span>
</div>
```

I do see the 'scroll' on the div, but faded. And my images are like this:

[Image1] [Image2] [Image3]

[Image4]

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try removing col-md-12

Comment: Add a fixed height to that parent div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `white-space: nowrap`:

```
<div style="overflow-x:scroll; white-space: nowrap" class="col-md-12">
```

Comment: Thank you, very small easy fix

Comment: I'd recommend not using inline styles, you'll find it a lot easier to maintain an external CSS file.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:
http://jsfiddle.net/danhaswings/nndhjp67/

**HTML**

```
<div id="slide">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#slide {
    width: auto;
    height: 100px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Dont know why, but this made my div with the images 'stick out', became too long instead of scollable (maybe has to do with my useage of ui.bootstrap modal)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these CSS rules to your wrapper `div`.

```
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: hidden;
width:100%;
```